# XSLT - Removing root node and first child node and placing grand child as root

Tags: xslt

Need help in following logic.

Source XML --

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://somenamespace.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
        <ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
            <ns0:children_level1 xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
                <Somedata/>
            </ns0:children_level1>
        </ns0:ToBeRoot>
        <ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
            <ns0:children_level2 xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
                <Somedata/>
            </ns0:children_level2>
        </ns0:ToBeRoot>
    </multimap:Message1>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Target XML (required)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
    <ns0:children_level1 xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
        <Somedata/>
    </ns0:children_level1>
    <ns0:children_level2 xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
        <Somedata/>
    </ns0:children_level2>
</ns0:ToBeRoot>
```

XSLT I tried,

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://somenamespace.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template for the document element -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()/node()/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ToBeRoot">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think something needs to be added to the template
<xsl:template match="ToBeRoot">
but struggling, please help.

The output using the above XSLT

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <ns0:children_level1 xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com" xmlns:multimap="http://somenamespace.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
                <Somedata/>
            </ns0:children_level1>
        
            <ns0:children_level2 xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com" xmlns:multimap="http://somenamespace.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
                <Somedata/>
            </ns0:children_level2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*/*/*"/>
    </ns0:ToBeRoot>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This leaves a redundant namespace declaration on the copied elements, which should be harmless. If you want to remove it, then you must recreate the elements  instead of copying them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*"/>
    </ns0:ToBeRoot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if your processor supports it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*/*/*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    </ns0:ToBeRoot>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> is it feasible to get the name ns0:ToBeRoot dynamically from the payload

Yes. Instead of:

```
    <ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
        <!-- ... -->
    </ns0:ToBeRoot>
```

use:

```
    <xsl:element name="{name(*/*[1])}" namespace="{namespace-uri(*/*[1])}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </xsl:element>
```

Comment: Many Thanks for this, will check and get back shortly, your help is greatly appreciated. meanwhile, I missed to add one thing, is it feasible to get the name  ns0:ToBeRoot dynamically from the payload instead of putting it in XSLT..

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Many Thanks Michael, this is absolutely spot on and saved the day for me :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you want

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/ns0:ToBeRoot[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ns0:ToBeRoot">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | following-sibling::ns0:ToBeRoot/node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or perhaps better XSLT 2 or 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/ns0:ToBeRoot[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ns0:ToBeRoot">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | following-sibling::ns0:ToBeRoot/node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had some mixup in your namespace declaration: `xmlns:ns0` was "http://mynamespace.com" in your XML, but "http://somenamespace.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge" in your XSLT.

Synchronizing them would give you the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com" xmlns:multimap="http://somenamespace.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- template for the document element -->
    <xsl:template match="/multimap:Messages">
        <xsl:element name="ns0:ToBeRoot" namespace="http://mynamespace.com">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="multimap:Message1/ns0:ToBeRoot/ns0:*" /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will give you the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ToBeRoot xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.com">
    <ns0:children_level1>
        <Somedata/>
    </ns0:children_level1>
    <ns0:children_level2>
        <Somedata/>
    </ns0:children_level2>
</ns0:ToBeRoot>
```

Comment: The result is NOT what your show: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtEp

Comment: I see... I developed this answer with `xsltproc` and with it, the output is as described. Maybe some flaw in the spec? Or a difference in the XDMs between XSLT-1.0 and XSLT-2.0?

Comment: Thank you michael.hor257k. Will check and get back. Much apprieciated, btw, is it feasible to add the ns0:ToBeRoot dynamically from payload.